# How do I prevent R from coercing this vector of Dates to numeric?

Tags: r

When combining a date vector with an NA, R will coerce the whole vector to numeric if NA appears first.  If NA does not appear first it will coerce to Date.

```
x <- Sys.Date()
c(NA, x)
# [1]    NA 16248
c(x, NA)
# [1] "2014-06-27" NA
```

How can I make it coerce to Date always, regardless of the order the NAs appear?  Secondly, what if I do not know the type of x, how can I still be certain that it coerces to the class of the vector x and not numeric?

Comment: As far as a more general solution is concerned, I guess the question would be why are you adding a NA value to the front. Would something as simple as `rev(c(x,NA))` work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of S3 method dispatch acting on the first argument `NA` and hence the default method is used which coerces everything up to numerics. The solution is to be explicit about the method to call, in this case `c.Date()`:

```
x <- Sys.Date()
xx <- c.Date(c.Date(NA, x))
xx
class(xx)

> xx
[1] NA           "2014-06-27"
> class(xx)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: It must be a bit more complicated than `c()` just converting to numeric when `NA` is the first param. Because things like `str(c(NA,TRUE)) ;str(c(NA,"OK")); str(c(NA,16.2))` behave as expected.

Comment: There was a similar issue with `cbind()` for data frames where when one did `cbind(x, my_data-frame)`, with `x` a vector, you got the default `cbind` method which coerced the data frame to a matrix and then added the vector as the first column. Then you had to call `cbind.data.frame()` directly. Now `cbind()` is clever enough to do the right thing for you: `class(cbind(Z = 1:10, data.frame(A = 1:10)))`

Comment: @MrFlick I was being specific to this case; `?c` documents a hierarchy of types. In your examples, the vectors are all atomic and simple base types. `"Date"` classed objects are not one of the atomic vector types but are actually a double with stated class `"Date"`. Once you drop the class you are back to a numeric vector hence the observed result.

Comment: @MrFlick "All elements of an atomic vector must be the same type, so when you attempt to combine different types they will be coerced to the most flexible type. Types from least to most flexible are: logical, integer, double and character." From here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Comment: @GavinSimpson Any thoughts on how to do this if the type of x is not known before hand?  That's really what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @andrew Would something like `fun <- getS3method(f = "c", class = class(x))` then `fun(c(NA, x))` work for you? This would need some wrapping to account for cases where there isn't a method for the specified class. Could be tricky to make this work in all situations...

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I was looking for thanks!