# What are the rules involved in coercing dates with the c() function

Tags: r, date, coercion

As I understand when the objects being concatenated with the c(...) function are of different types they are coerced into a single type which is the type of the output object

According the the R documentation

> The output type is determined from the highest type of the components
>   in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex <
>   character < list < expression.

Dates have a data type of double so if paired with a character should result in a character, if paired with an integer should result in a double, as we can see here

```
> a<-as.Date("2019-01-01")
> c("a",a)
[1] "a"     "17901"
> c(1L,a)
[1]     1 17901
> typeof(c(1L,a))
[1] "double"
```

However if the date is first the function tries to convert the other values to class Date. This does not seem to match the behaviour from the documentation

```
> c(a,1)
[1] "2019-01-05" "1970-01-02"
> c(a,"a")
[1] "2019-01-05" NA
Warning message: In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What additional rules are being applied here? Or alternatively what have I misunderstood about the situation?

Comment: Related: [How do I prevent R from coercing this vector of Dates to numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460679/how-do-i-prevent-r-from-coercing-this-vector-of-dates-to-numeric)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions can be "overloaded" in R based on the data type of the first parameter. You can see there is a special `c.Date` function that is run when you call `c` with `Date` object as the first parameter. You can see all the "special" `c()` functions with `methods("c")`. These functions can (and do) define different rules than the base `c()` function. But since overloading only happens based on the data type of the first parameter, the order in which the values appear makes a big difference.